How can I save state of widgets inside TabBar widget
I am new to Flutter and have some problem. I have some sort of application with some widgets. I pick widget called StateTimerPage with different types of timer and when I leave this page I want to save state of widgets nested in the TabBar widget. What can I do? (in other words I want timer to run while user is in other widgets)
**This is a common widget for timers **
import 'package:cgk/timer1.dart';
import 'package:cgk/timer2.dart';
import 'package:cgk/timer3.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class StateTimerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const StateTimerPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StateTimerPageState createState() => _StateTimerPageState();
}

class _StateTimerPageState extends State<StateTimerPage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    final size = MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .size;
    return Center(
        child: DefaultTabController(
            length: 3,
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: const Color(0xff4397de),
                centerTitle: true,
                title: const Text("Таймеры"),
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                bottom: TabBar(
                    indicatorColor: const Color(0xff418ecd),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(
                        icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                            'assets/Group 1.svg',
                            width: 25.0,
                            height: 25.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                          icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                              'assets/Group 2.svg',
                              width: 25.0,
                              height: 25.0,
                          )
                      ),
                      Tab(
                          icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                              'assets/Group 3.svg',
                              width: 25.0,
                              height: 25.0,
                          )
                      )
                    ]
                ),
              ),
              body: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  StateTimer1Page(),
                  StateTimer2Page(),
                  StateTimer3Page(),
                ],
              ),
            )
        )
    );
  }
}

And this is an example of a timer
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:cgk/menu.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class StateTimer1Page extends StatefulWidget {
  const StateTimer1Page({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StateTimer1PageState createState() => _StateTimer1PageState();
}

// Класс Таймера
class _StateTimer1PageState extends State<StateTimer1Page> with WidgetsBindingObserver/*, AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin*/{
  Timer? _timer;
  late int _waitTime;
  var _percent = 1.0;
  var isStart = false;
  var timeStr = '05:00';

  //@override
  //bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    _waitTime = 60;
    _calculateTime();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    _timer?.cancel();
  }

  // Функция кнопки Старт
  void start(BuildContext context) {
    if (_waitTime > 0) {
      setState(() {
        isStart = true;
      });
      _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
        _waitTime -= 1;
        _calculateTime();
        if (_waitTime <= 0) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
              .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('Finished')));
          sound! ? AudioPlayer().play(AssetSource('startTimer.mp3')) : null;
          pause();
        }
      });
    }
  }

  // Функция кнопки Перезагрузки
  void restart() {
    _waitTime = 60;
    _calculateTime();
  }

  // Функция кнопки Паузы
  void pause() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    setState(
          () {
        isStart = false;
      },
    );
  }

  // Дополнительная функция для вычисления времени
  void _calculateTime() {
    var minuteStr = (_waitTime ~/ 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    var secondStr = (_waitTime % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    setState(() {
      _percent = _waitTime / 60;
      timeStr = '$minuteStr:$secondStr';
    });
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) pause();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //super.build(context);
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xff3987c8),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: size.height * 0.3,
                  width: size.height * 0.3,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    value: _percent,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                    strokeWidth: 11,
                    color: const Color(0xff235d8c),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: Text(
                    timeStr,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 50,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                    height: size.height * 0.35,
                    width: size.height * 0.35,
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/Group 6.svg',
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    width: size.width * 0.05,
                    height: size.height * 0.05,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: size.height * 0.15,
                  width: size.height * 0.15,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                      heroTag: "btn1",
                      backgroundColor: const Color(0xff418ecd),
                      onPressed: () {
                        isStart ? pause() : start(context);
                      },
                      child: isStart
                          ? const Icon(
                        Icons.pause,
                        size: 80,
                        color: Color(0xff235d8c),
                      )
                          : const Icon(
                        Icons.play_arrow_outlined,
                        size: 80,
                        color: Color(0xff235d8c),
                      )),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: size.height * 0.15,
                  width: size.height * 0.15,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                      heroTag: "btn2",
                      backgroundColor: const Color(0xff418ecd),
                      onPressed: () {
                        restart();
                      },
                      child: const Icon(
                        Icons.restart_alt,
                        size: 80,
                        color: Color(0xff235d8c),
                      )),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I've tried the AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin with both of StateTimerPage and Timers but it didn't help me.

Why don't you store the state outside of the widget tree?

@Thomas how can I do it? Can it be PageStorage?

You should implement a separate data layer of objects that you can then access from your widgets. Typically you use a locator like get_it or riverpod for that. In the most basic form it can be a global variable. If you want your UI to react on data changes in the data layer you need any form of state management like watch_it, riverpod or bloc
